# Nested UserControls in Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, xamlparseexception

I am trying to create a Windows Phone app that will take use a similar UI element in multiple user controls.

One user control is loaded by the main xaml and this user control consists of another user controls.  The user controls are all in the same directory below where the main xaml exists.

I get an XamlParseException on the following line in my g.i.cs file for the nested control:

```
 System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri("/MyApp;component/UI/NestedControl.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));
```

I think it is doubling the component/UI portions of the path as the parent user control already resides in this directory.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This exception typically means that the XAML parser cannot find the referenced XAML, or that you have invalid XAML for your NestedControl class.

Without further code, it is hard to determine the root cause. I would suggest deleting these classes until your project compiles, then slowly adding them back again, compiling each time. This will help you identify where the problem lies.